# pip fail to install pkg because - not a supported wheel on this platform inspite linux fit requrments

Tags: python, linux, pip, redhat

we are installing the pkg:
MarkupSafe-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl by pip

we download the pkg from - https://pypi.org/project/MarkupSafe/#files

we have redhat OS with version 7.2

as the follwing:

```
 pip install -v --no-index --find-links PIP/ MarkupSafe-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Requirement 'MarkupSafe-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
MarkupSafe-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    wheel_cache
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 275, in populate_requirement_set
    wheel_cache=wheel_cache
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 197, in from_line
    wheel.filename
UnsupportedWheel: MarkupSafe-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

we get - is not a supported wheel on this platform.

but the Linux versions should be fit to this pkg

we verify by **uname -a**

```
 uname -a

Linux Master 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 more /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

so  what is happened here ?

Comment: What version of python are you using? cp27 refers to CPython 2.7...

Comment: Python 2.7.5 ( version of python )

Comment: Does the source version work? https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/7e/1b4c2e05809a4414ebce0892fe1e32c14ace86ca7d50c70f00979ca9b3a3/MarkupSafe-1.1.0.tar.gz

Comment: Can we see the result of `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`? I want to see if your python is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: `pip` tells you that it can't find the wheel file. Does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

This could be happened due to out-of-date pip.

Try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: little strange because we installed the latest version - python-pip-7.1.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm

Comment: `pip 7.1.0` is certainly not the latest version. The current latest version is [18.1](https://pypi.org/project/pip/18.1/).